# Get lines with maximum values in the column using awk, uniq and sort

Tags: shell-script, awk, sort, uniq

I have a file with next format

```
2011-12-01 user1 access1
2011-12-01 user1 access2
2011-12-01 user2 access2
2011-12-01 user4 access2
2011-12-02 user1 access1
2012-01-01 user3 access1
2012-01-01 user4 access2
```

I would like to have an output that for every user shows the last date, so

```
2011-12-02 user1 access1
2011-12-01 user1 access2
2011-12-01 user2 access2
2012-01-01 user3 access1
2012-01-01 user4 access2
```

I tried something like this:

```
less myfile.txt | sort -k1r | uniq -f 1  | sort -b -k1
```

but it isn't seems to work right.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Step 0: you want `cat`, not `less`. Somebody will now surely point out that `cat myfile | sort` is worse than `sort myfile`, but I find it easier when having long pipe sequences.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `<myfile sort | uniq | sort` keeps the logical order while not introducing a spurious process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
cat myfile.txt| sort -k1 -r | sort --unique --stable -k2,3
```

(see my comment regarding `cat` above). The first sort will put the newest dates to the top. The second sort will sort by user+access, but, by giving `--stable`, will keep the previous order of lines that have the same user+access combination, i.e. newest still on top. Giving `--unique`, only the first line of a run with equal user+access combination is shown. (You can replace it with `| uniq -f1`, I'd think, if it happens to be a GNU extension your sort doesn't have.)

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there, just need to adjust the `sort` options:

```
sort -k2,2 -k1,1r myfile.txt | uniq -f1
```

That is: sort by user and reverse date, leave only first appearance of user + access.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it just with a single call to `awk`

```
awk '($1 > a[$2,$3]){a[$2,$3]=$1}END{for(x in a){split(x,b,SUBSEP);print a[x],b[1],b[2]}}' in
```